# Unable to format usb

Tags: windows-7, usb, formatting

I am unable to format my usb (4GB SanDisk). It says it's write protected.

Whenever I attach it to my PC, I get an alert about a virus infection (auto-run.inf + recycler) but no action is taken due to the write protection. How do I fix this?

In regedit I was unable to find `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\**StorageDevicePolicies**`

I tried:

- diskpart
- regedit
- formatting tools

Answer (score 0):

To save the day you can use the [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/) live Linux distribution. Make a bootable CD or USB, boot from it and then use the **Erase Disk** utility to format your USB drive.

Here is a simple [video instruction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8t2ZXOMGKY) from Youtube.

PS: No Linux knowledge is necessary. Everything is done in GUI by the means of mouse.

Comment: is it same as gparted partitioning tool

Comment: No, it isn't. See the Youtube link I provided.